# What is the intended way to input text into an ionic hybrid app input field with appium? sendkeys: cannot focus element

Tags: ionic-framework, focus, appium, sendkeys

Appium Server v 1.9.1
Appium Java Client v6.1.0

I am using Appium to automate a hybrid app built with Ionic 4. Everything is working great except for Appium's sendkeys method (element.sendKeys("");). When attempting to interact with the  elements, I can tap on them using .click() perfectly fine, but if I attempt to send keys I get the following 'cannot focus element' error:

Appium Java Client Logs:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)


at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:45)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement.execute(AndroidElement.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:100)
```

Appium Server Logs

```
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/3c1b8a7a-a990-4ffa-be83-5b3fcc1d0a2c/element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:5309/wd/hub/session/027c8d0e01db56c76726b5f3842aa1d2/element] with body: {"using":"css selector","value":"#logs-filter"}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"027c8d0e01db56c76726b5f3842aa1d2","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.16747293389607476-4"}}
[JSONWP Proxy] Replacing sessionId 027c8d0e01db56c76726b5f3842aa1d2 with 3c1b8a7a-a990-4ffa-be83-5b3fcc1d0a2c
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/3c1b8a7a-a990-4ffa-be83-5b3fcc1d0a2c/element 200 76 ms - 107
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/3c1b8a7a-a990-4ffa-be83-5b3fcc1d0a2c/element/0.16747293389607476-4/value
[HTTP] {"id":"0.16747293389607476-4","text":"asd","value":["a","s","d"]}
[W3C] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/3c1b8a7a-a990-4ffa-be83-5b3fcc1d0a2c/element/0.16747293389607476-4/value' to command name 'setValue'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/3c1b8a7a-a990-4ffa-be83-5b3fcc1d0a2c/element/0.16747293389607476-4/value] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:5309/wd/hub/session/027c8d0e01db56c76726b5f3842aa1d2/element/0.16747293389607476-4/value] with body: {"id":"0.16747293389607476-4","text":"asd","value":["a","s","d"]}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"027c8d0e01db56c76726b5f3842aa1d2","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: cannot focus element\n  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"}}
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: ProxyRequestError: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: The request to /wd/hub/session/3c1b8a7a-a990-4ffa-be83-5b3fcc1d0a2c/element/0.16747293389607476-4/value has failed
[debug] [W3C]     at JWProxy.proxy$ (C:\Users\jstrickland\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\jsonwp-proxy\proxy.js:182:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at tryCatch (C:\Users\jstrickland\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
[debug] [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\jstrickland\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
[debug] [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\jstrickland\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
[debug] [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\jstrickland\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
[debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 13 to UnknownError
```

I've confirmed my context and window handle is correct (I couldn't click element if it wasn't).

My question is how is this *intended* to work? Is sendKeys the intended way to send text to a html input element in an ionic app with appium? If so - this seems like a bug, as appium doesn't have another mechanism for this, and I need to send them a bug report. But perhaps this is not the intended way and I'm making a mistake?

Some thoughts on why this is occurring:
I hypothesize that the root of evil here is that the ion-input element in reality conjures a child input element which is a standard input element in the HTML tree. You can see this via inspection from chrome. I think appium is getting confused because it is trying to treat the ion-input as a input and waiting for ion-input to be focusable as opposed to the input element. This explains why I can click on the thing but I can't send keys to it.

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, here are some workarounds I've found to get around this for the time being.

- You can use javascript to accomplish this: `driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", element, "text-to-send");`
- You can click the element and then do a LOT of keyevents IE:
  `AndroidDriver d = (AndroidDriver) driver;
          d.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.A));
          d.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.B));
          d.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.c));`
- You can select the child element of the < ion-input > which is a standard input and perform sendkeys on this element.

  `List<MobileElement> l = e.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));
              l.get(0).sendKeys(text);`